# Is there an analog of the p-series test for infinite products?

Tags: sequences-and-series, infinite-product

What I mean:

P-series: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^p}$$An infinite product "P-series": $$\prod_{n=1}^\infty(1+\frac{1}{n^p})$$ For what $p\in\mathbb{R}$ does the infinite series converge? Diverge? Has this been considered before?

Comment: *Has this been considered before?* - [Yeah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product#Convergence_criteria).

Comment: Google ["Coriolis test" and "infinite product"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22Coriolis+test%22+%22infinite+product%22) and see [*Some Elementary Properties of Infinite Products*](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324060) by Edgar M. E. Wermuth.

Comment: @EdgarM.E.Wermuth That's funny, the first thing that comes up in the search is this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let

$$p_n=\prod_{k=1}^n\left(1+\frac1{k^p}\right)$$
the partial product and then we have
$$\ln p_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln\left(1+\frac1{k^p}\right)$$
and since
$$\ln\left(1+\frac1{k^p}\right)\sim_\infty\frac 1{k^p}$$
then the sequence $(\ln p_n)$ is convergent if and only if $p>1$ hence $(p_n)$ is also convergent if and only if $p>1$